# Code for identifying the k simultaneous transmitters out of n

Tags: coding-theory, compression

I'm working on an application and wondering if there's a name for the code I'm describing and any further reading.

Given $n$ items, assign a binary string for each such that the bitwise-or of any subset of up to $k$ items will be unique.

Examples:

When $k=1$, you can just assign each to a different non-zero integer, and you need $\lceil log_2 (n+1) \rceil$ bits.

When $k=n$, you can use a unary encoding with a single bit set for each integer, and you need $n$ bits.

When $n=8$, $k=2$, there are 37 subsets that need to be identified. With a computer search I found that the optimal encoding uses 7 bits:

```
k0 0000101
k1 0001010
k2 0001100
k3 0010010
k4 0100001
k5 0100010
k6 1000001
k7 1010000
k0 | k1 0001111
k0 | k2 0001101
k0 | k3 0010111
k0 | k4 0100101
k0 | k5 0100111
k0 | k6 1000101
k0 | k7 1010101
k1 | k2 0001110
k1 | k3 0011010
k1 | k4 0101011
k1 | k5 0101010
k1 | k6 1001011
k1 | k7 1011010
k2 | k3 0011110
k2 | k4 0101101
k2 | k5 0101110
k2 | k6 1001101
k2 | k7 1011100
k3 | k4 0110011
k3 | k5 0110010
k3 | k6 1010011
k3 | k7 1010010
k4 | k5 0100011
k4 | k6 1100001
k4 | k7 1110001
k5 | k6 1100011
k5 | k7 1110010
k6 | k7 1010001
```

Is there a known method for generating reasonably efficient codes of this type? If I have $k \ll n$, is the shortest code closer to $\lceil log_2 \sum_{i=0}^{k} {n \choose i} \rceil$ bits, or is it proportional to the trivial solution in $n$ bits?

Comment: I don't have the time to think about this right now. I do want to comment that the basic requirement (in my opinion) resembles that of *Optical CDMA*. There the different users were transmitting a sequence of bits via a shared optical fibre. And "light ON" + "light ON" collision obviously leads to "light ON" matching your bitwise OR metric. IIRC the people designing optical CDMA sequences were also worried about getting a user synchronized, which translated to identifying the sequences up to cyclic shifts also.

Comment: So I'm not at all positive that the optical CDMA codes would do what you want. You may find something useful with that buzzword anyway. Also, there is a fair change that something simpler works in you scenario, as I tend to suggest anything I've seen that seems remotely related :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is related to combinatorial group testing. Specifically $k-$disjunct codes or $k-$cover free families are designed to ensure no union (OR combination) of $k$ sets covers (masks) another set (codeword).

Kautz-Singleton had an early construction for such codes. It was recently shown to be as good as randomised constructions [see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01457).

OOCs are related but there you have to include all cyclic shifts of any sequence in the family.

**Edit:** Erdos, Frankl and Furedi proved that the maximum size of such a code (given $n$ and $k$) is upper bounded by
$$
k+\binom{n}{\lceil (n-k)/\binom{k+1}{2} \rceil},
$$
see [here](https://www.bsmath.hu/19summer/paper2.pdf), though Dyachov and Rykov have a better upper bound mentioned in that paper. For explicit construction details the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.3876.pdf) by Porat and Rothschild is good to read.